# Generating WSDL for a single ServiceStack service

Tags: c#, wsdl, servicestack

Is there a way to get a WSDL for a single ServiceStack service?  For example, if I override the AppHost.Configure method and register a service, like so...

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    this.RegisterService<MySoapService>("/MySoapService");
}
```

Could I configure ServiceStack to generate a WSDL for just the MySoapService service? Something like...

```
https://mycompany.com/MySoapService?wsdl
```

I find that getting a WSDL using [...]/soap11 gives me a WSDL for all services hosted by the application.  This is a problem when REST-only services are not SOAP complaint.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `/soap11` and `/soap12` WSDL endpoints return all ServiceStack Services.

You can hide Services that aren't compatible with [ServiceStack's SOAP Support](http://docs.servicestack.net/soap-support) by marking them with the `[Exclude(Feature.Soap)]` attribute which will hide them from the WSDL.

Comment: Thanks.  That helps for what I need right now.  Although, it seems excessive to describe all services in only one WSDL.

Comment: @Jason that's what WSDL's do, describe all Services available at the SOAP endpoint.

Comment: Understood. I suppose my question would have been better worded to ask how I might setup different SOAP endpoints in ServiceStack; allowing a separate WSDL for each service.  Similar to how a WCF project allows a different WSDL for each service endpoint (e.g. .../separateService.svc?wsdl). This would allow me to leverage ServiceStack as a container for lots of modularized services, while reducing the code .NET clients generate for only those services it will consume.

Comment: @Jason ServiceStack doesn't allow multiple SOAP endpoints in the same AppHost, so your options are to create multiple AppHost's each referencing the Services you want available for each AppHost/endpoint or manually splitting the WSDL into multiple smaller WSDLs. Note: they can just be "dummy" AppHost's, i.e. solely used to generate the different smaller WSDLs, you can still use a single AppHost to host all Services.